# How to add cache-control for existing s3 objects in terraform?

Tags: terraform

there are over 10000 objects in s3 already, and I wanna add cache-control for all these objects by terraform. Is there a way to achieve the goal in terraform?

Comment: Is Terraform managing every object in your S3 bucket? This seems like an odd use of Terraform if so.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR nope, did not use terraform to manage every object. and I did not find a solution for the question in terraform.

Comment: There's no way to set a default cache control header for objects in an S3 bucket and it would probably be a bad idea to use Terraform to manage every object in the bucket so I'd say no. However it depends on what you're trying to do. If you can put CloudFront in front of the S3 bucket then you can set min and max TTLs on the cache control headers independently of what is set by the origin (in your case the S3 bucket).

Comment: I want my application to read contents from browser cache, so I think add cloudFront is not the right choice

Comment: Yes it needs to be done from s3 end. Have you found any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to make it using terraform, but you can use the follow command

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://bucketX/ s3://bucketX/ --metadata-directive REPLACE --recursive --cache-control max-age=31536000
```

Comment: how can you change it also for future files, your command will only do the change for existing files